# Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL when I open MAMP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I just start MAMP and it shows:

> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: **Got error: 2013:** Lost
>   connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet',
>   system error: 0 when trying to connect

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from [this reply](https://serverfault.com/q/29597) on ServerFault:

> This could be very bad, 2013 means that the thread servicing the mysqldump process has died. This could be because the InnoDB engine on the server has detected an error while reading the database file for you database. As mysqldump has to read all the pages for all of your database to make the backup it is likely to trigger any latent corruption that your application may avoid during it day to day activity.
>
> If you run your mysql command and it reports that your connection id is a low number then you server has probably restarted itself. You should check your mysqld.log immediately to find out why.